# Remotely search AD for computer object without OU

Tags: c#, active-directory, remote-access

Good Day All,

I have been asked to write out some code to find a computer object in AD I haven't been given the OU's that these objects could be in (which isn't helpful at all - obviously). I've determined that I can remotely connect to the AD server with the lines:

```
DirectoryEntry startingPoint = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=Zone,DC=Corp,DC=COM", "UserName", "Password");

//Find all OUs
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(startingPoint);
searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=Computer)";

foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
{
}
```

Unfortunately, the only information I do have is that all the objects will be no further than 3 OU's deep. So I'd like to know how to go through each of the OU's going that deep in each one I come to until I find the designated host name. I'm not exactly sure how to work that out. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;` Then use a proper filter that includes the hostname you're looking for. Maybe something like `$"(&(objectCategory=Computer)(cn={hostname}))"`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change the `SearchScope` to `Subtree` and then include the hostname as part of the filter. I would then use `FindOne()` instead of `FindAll()`:

```
DirectoryEntry startingPoint = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=Zone,DC=Corp,DC=COM", "UserName", "Password");

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(startingPoint)
    {
        SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
        Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=Computer)(cn={hostname}))"
    };

SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
```